# Authenticate Jenkins users against JIRA

Tags: jenkins, jira

We are currently setting up Confluence, JIRA and Jenkins and I would rather have only one user database that all tools can use than having to create separate accounts in each tool. Google tells me that Jenkins can authenticate and authorize users against Atlassian Crowd. Confluence can use Crowd and also JIRA for user management.

But can Jenkins use JIRA (not Crowd) as its user database, to authenticate and authorize users against it?

Comment: I've done that using Crowd and the Apache crowd plugin. Crowd plugin in Jenkins was broken at that time. If you can somehow get a apache password file out of your Jira directory, then it's fairly simple. I'm not aware of any jenkins plugin providing this.

Comment: JIRA 4.3 took parts of Crowd and embedded them. I'd start with the Crowd for Jenkins plugin and see if you can't tweak it to refer to JIRA. Atlassian is likely to say that this is the job of Crowd.

Comment: I did try that, using the Crowd2 plugin and configuring it to connect to the JIRA server. That didn't work, keeps throwing an exception. So it doesn't work out of the box.

Answer (score 23):

One method is with the Crowd2 (Jenkins plugin).

#### From Jira

1. Goto Admin Cog > User Management
2. "JIRA User Server" (left side)
3. Click "+Add application" (top right side)

   *Notes: To specify a port with the IP address(es) in Jira, use XX.XX.XX.XX/PORT format. Jira user must have admin permissions.*

   [image: Jira User Server]

#### From Jenkins

1. Goto "Manage Jenkins" (left side) > Manage Plugins > Available Tab
2. Download crowd2 plugin
3. Goto "Manage Jenkins" (left side) > "Configure Global Security"

   *Notes: Requires Jenkins admin access.*

   [image: Configure Global Security]

Comment: I can confirm that this works with Jenkins 1.572 and Jira v6.1.2!

Comment: Excellent thank you for this, confirmed with Jira 6.2.3 and Jenkins 1.577

Comment: I can confirm this with Jira 7.2.0 and Jenkins 2.33. Such a good feeling if a configuration just works...!