# Jenkins Crowd2 authentication broken on passing jira traffic through Cloudflare

Tags: jenkins, jira, cloudflare

We use jira for authentication to our Jenkins sites([Authenticate Jenkins users against JIRA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411208/authenticate-jenkins-users-against-jira)). For this purpose we use Crowd 2 plugin in Jenkins. We use Cloudflare for our DNS Service. The Authentication System works perfectly fine when we have DNS only flag on in Cloudflare for our Jira site. But once we enable "Traffic to this hostname will go through Cloudflare" for the Jira Site in Cloudflare the Authentication System breaks for some of our Jenkins Sites. Authentication for some of the Jenkins servers still work fine.

We have tried resetting the password for the Application and setting new password in Crowd 2 plugin and as well as in Jira user server section. But for the servers where this Authentication is broken, this approach doesn't work.

This is the error which I can see happening in Jenkins log when I try to authenticate through the Crowd 2 plugin in Jenkins:

```
SEVERE: The connection check failed.
com.atlassian.crowd.exception.InvalidCrowdServiceException: The following URL does not specify a valid Crowd User Management REST service: https://*******/rest/usermanagement/1/search?entity-type=user&start-index=0&max-results=1&expand=user
    at com.atlassian.crowd.integration.rest.service.RestExecutor$MethodExecutor.executeCrowdServiceMethod(RestExecutor.java:455)
    at com.atlassian.crowd.integration.rest.service.RestExecutor$MethodExecutor.andReceive(RestExecutor.java:341)
    at com.atlassian.crowd.integration.rest.service.RestCrowdClient.searchUsers(RestCrowdClient.java:511)
    at com.atlassian.crowd.integration.rest.service.RestCrowdClient.testConnection(RestCrowdClient.java:500)
    at de.theit.jenkins.crowd.CrowdSecurityRealm$DescriptorImpl.doTestConnection(CrowdSecurityRealm.java:556)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:408)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:212)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:145)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:537)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:739)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:870)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:282)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:739)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:870)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:668)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:128)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Does anyone have any idea why Crowd 2 plugin of Jenkins throws the above mentioned error?